# Change json content displayed in parent component based on child component menu option

Tags: json, reactjs

I have an app with a drop menu in the Navbar component that contains clothing sizes (S,M,L).  All the clothing is being rendered in the parent App component from json. I want to re-render the section of the App component that displays the items with items from the json based on the menu selection. Any tips appreciated.

I'm rendering everything from json initially and updating state when the drop menu changes but can't re-render the products in the parent component (displayed in grid)

JSON

```
const tops =  [{
            index: 0,
            isSale: true,
            isExclusive: false,
            price: "$18.88",
            productImage: "product-1.jpg",
            productName: "Striped top",
            size: ["XS", "S", "L", "XL"]
          },
          {
            index: 1,
            isSale: false,
            isExclusive: false,
            price: "$25.44",
            productImage: "product-2.jpg",
            productName: "Denim top",
            size: ["XS", "S"]
          },
          {
            index: 2,
            isSale: false,
            isExclusive: true,
            price: "$12.93",
            productImage: "product-3.jpg",
            productName: "Plain cotton top",
            size: ["S", "M"]
...
          }];
```

Top, Navbar and App components

```
let saleExclusive = null;

class Top extends Component {

            constructor(props) {
              super(props);

              this.state = {
                              id: null, 
                              productName: null,
                              productImage: null,
                              isSale: null,
                              isExclusive: null,
                              size: null,
                              price: null,
                              saleExclusive: null
              }
            }

              render (){

                if(this.props.isSale===true){
                      saleExclusive = <div className="btn btn-danger m20">Sale</div>
                    } 
                    else if(this.props.isExclusive===true){
                      saleExclusive = <div className="btn btn-success m20">Exclusive</div>
                    } 
                    else {
                      saleExclusive = <div className="blank"></div>
                }

              return (
                <div className="col-3 displayBox">
                  <div className="row text-center"><img src={require("./assets/images/"+this.props.productImage)} width="90%" height="90%" alt="Select this" /></div>
                  <div className="row">
                    {  saleExclusive }  
                  </div>
                  <div className="row h50">
                  <div className="col-7 text-left prod-desc">{this.props.productName}</div>
                  <div className="col-3 prod-price">{this.props.price}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            }
          }


class NavBar extends Component {

            constructor(props) {
                super(props);

            this.state = {
                selectValue: '',
                selectedSize: '',
                data:''
                }
            }



              componentDidUpdate(){
                console.log(this.state.selectedSize)
              }

            render (){
              var handleChange  =   this.props.handleChange;
                return( <div className="row navbarpoz">
                                <div className="col-6 text-left heading">
                                {this.props.navTitle}
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-6 text-right">
                                    <select id="availablesizes"   
                                            defaultValue={this.selectValue} 
                                            onChange={() => handleChange(this.value)}>
                                        <option>Filter by size</option>
                                        <option value="XS">XS</option>
                                        <option value="S">S</option>
                                        <option value="M">M</option>
                                        <option value="L">L</option>
                                        <option value="XL">XL</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    );
              }
        }     

class App extends Component {

            constructor(props){
              super(props);
              this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
              this.state = {
                data: "...let's shop",
                selectedSize: ''
              }
            }

            handleChange(size) {
              this.setState({
                selectedSize: size
              })
              alert(size);
            }

            getData(){
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                  data: "Women's tops",
                  selectedSize: 'S'
                })
              }, 1000)
            }

            componentDidMount(){
              this.getData();
            }

    render() { 
    return (
            <div className="container">
              {this.state.selectedSize}
                <NavBar navTitle={this.state.data}/>
                <div id="itemGrid" className="text-center">
                {tops.map(tops => (
                    <Top handleChange={this.handleChange} 
                        key={tops.id} 
                        productName={tops.productName}
                        productImage={tops.productImage}
                        isSale={tops.isSale}
                        isExclusive={tops.isExclusive}
                        size={tops.size}
                        price={tops.price}
                    />
                ))}
                </div>            
            </div>
            );
        }
    }


export default App
```

When user selects XS from the menu then only the json with size: ["XS"] needs to display in the grid. At present the parent isn't getting updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<select />` in `Navbar` you're using `this.value` but `this` here refers to the `Navbar` component which doesn't set any `value` so it's always `null`.

```
onChange={() => handleChange(this.value)}>
```

What you want to do is this :

```
onChange={event => handleChange(event.taget.value)}>
```

Then in your `App` you'll need to filter `tops` with the `selectedSize` state :

```
const suitableTops = tops.filter(top => top.size.includes(this.state.selectedSize));
```

Before mapping it like you already do in `render`:

```
suitableTops.map(top => <Top key={top.id} {...top} />);
```

But the result will be empty before the user selects a size because `this.state.selectedSize` is default to `''`, so you may want to set an existing size by default to your `selectedSize` state. Or wrap the filter in a condition.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now updating state in Navbar and working on binding it to the parent to re-render.

Comment: @Stev Your welcome, will you accept or upvote the answer ?

Comment: @Stev I updated my answer with what you need to update the parent

Comment: The filter's working. Definite upvote. I still need to re-render the products after the menu changes so I'll hold off as answered. Tnx

Comment: Thanks @adesurirey. I was able to solve it with the help of this answer.

Comment: @Stev Click on the check icon under the votes count